# cannot display IE 8 and down no support message

Tags: reactjs, webpack, modernizr

I created a website using reactjs and webpack, I am using modernizr to show support for specific features, but I want to show a message in IE 8 and below that I do not support these browsers. the problem is that when loading the website, it fails since webpack and react do not support it.
my question is, how can i display the message? is there a way to show it before react loads? or maybe there is a way to make it work just for that message?

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional comments to load special CSS and print HTML only in IE8.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Example:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<p class="unsupported-ie">This page is not supported for IE8 and lower versions of IE.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

And you can even load CSS in `<head>`:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" href="/unsupported-ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: + include the application JS in a "gte ie 9" and/or "not ie" conditional comment so it doesn't even have to be downloaded.

Comment: thats actually preetey good, are there solutions like this for other browsers btw? IE is my main issue but lets say, is there a way to make a condition that doesnt specifically say IE X ?

Comment: I do not think so, even newer IE does not support it (from official documentation: *As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode. Use feature detection to provide effective fallback strategies for website features that aren't supported by the browser. For more info about standards mode, see Defining Document Compatibility.*). But you can use it without any problem for IE up to version 9.

Comment: i see, do you maybe know of another method to detect features before my webpack and react load? if webpack was loaded i could use modernizr library but i cant "require" or "import" anything before that..

Comment: Best advice I can give you is to write applications universally for all modern and common browsers :-) Your developer's life will be easier and happier :-) Trying to detect client's browser and fit pages to them is great way to the maintenance hell with a uncertain outcome.

Comment: ye im not trying to support old browsers but we need to be able to display a message that we dont support those browsers

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, I have used simple Java script  to identify browser & and   its  version.A pop up message will  appear and will give appropriate message- if version is compatible then load site else stop the user from proceeding ahead- 
Below is simple HTML page:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style>
               .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
       }

        /* Modal Content */
       .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
           padding: 20px;
           border: 1px solid #888;
           width: 80%;
       }

       /* The Close Button */
          .close {
               color: #aaaaaa;
               float: right;
               font-size: 28px;
               font-weight: bold;
              }

             .close:hover,
             .close:focus {
              color: #000;
              text-decoration: none;
               cursor: pointer;
           }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="IEValidationMessage();">

   <!-- this is the DIV used for showing message box -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div id="closeBtn" class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
           <div id="divMessagebody"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
        var span = document.getElementById("closeBtn");
            span.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
       // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
          window.onclick = function (event) {
           if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
          }
      }
       function IEValidationMessage() {
           modal.style.display = "block";
           if (document.documentMode < 9) {
              document.getElementById("divMessagebody").innerHTML = "Please Use IE 9 or Above.)";
          }
          else {
             document.getElementById("divMessagebody").innerHTML = "congrats Site is compatible in this IE version ";
         }
         if (document.documentMode ==undefined) {
             document.getElementById("divMessagebody").innerHTML = "Please use IE9 or higher only.   ";
         }
     }

  </script>

   </body>
```